# Can we improve signposting to Chat, for new users?

Tags: feature-request, chat, new-users

When I started on this site, although I saw Chat mentioned here and there I wasn't fully aware how to find it and use it.  I think there could be better signposting for new users of what advantages chat offers, how it can be used, and what rooms are available to math stackexchange users.

Even now after over a year using the site, I discover new chat rooms and features. I think a page describing some of the most important chat resources would be a good improvement to math.stackexchange.  This page might be signposted from the first post screen, and from various issues such as question closed, deleted, downvoted etc.

Comment: I agree that this would be useful. Do you have specific recommendations about what to change?

Comment: @StellaBiderman I'm probably not familiar enough with the ui and ux to be able to recommend how. I remember there is a how to ask a question page and other guidance pages. I'm not sure if they mention chat, but if they do it may be better if they mention the specific chat pages in math. that you can go to.